# Who of these characters has a more legitimate claim on the Iron Throne?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "Eastwatch" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E05), in the scene with Gilly and Sam, Gilly is reading from the records of High Septon Maynard. From this scene, we can infer that this High Septon performed an annulment for Rhaegar Targaryen and married him in secret. I think that it is safe to assume that it was to Lyanna Stark.

From earlier episodes, we know that this was the coupling that produced Jon Snow. Now, given that they were married and that Rhaegar was the eldest of the siblings, does this make Jon the actual heir over Daenerys?

Comment: "From earlier episodes, we know that this was the coupling the produced Jon Snow":  How?

Comment: @Dawny33 Season 6 Episode 10

Comment: So is Jon a cousin / brother to Deny or he could be a likely partner / spouse to her? One or both?

Comment: @AlexS Rhaegar (Jon's father) was Daenerys' brother, so Jon would be her nephew. That doesn't mean he's not also a likely partner/spouse (Targaryen's have a history of marrying each other), though.

Comment: @AlexS He is Dany's nephew by her eldest brother Rhaegar. He can be her King Consort (Targaryens practice incest to keep the bloodline pure). Mostly it is between siblings. King Maegor however took his niece Rhaena Targaryen as a bride, so there is inverse precedent.

Comment: Argh, spoiler in question title appearing in hottest questions sidebar!! Can someone fix? :(

Comment: Fixing the spoiler in the title is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 21):

In show, he does have a better claim.

From S07E05:

> Gilly: What does "annulment" mean?
>
> Sam: It's when a man sets aside his lawful wife.
>
> Gilly: Maynard says here that **he issued an annulment for a Prince "Ragger"
>   and remarried him to someone else** at the same time in a secret
>   ceremony in Dorne. Is that a common thing in the south or--?

Here Gilly is reading records of a High Septon from days of Prince Rhaegar and she discovers that he annulled the marriage of Prince "Ragger" (Rhaegar) and married him to someone else. That someone can only be Lyanna. So it is all but confirmed in the Show that Rhaegar did marry her and Jon is legitimate child.

So he has a better claim because a grandson (Jon) by an elder son (Rhaegar) comes before a younger son (Viserys) and a daughter (Daenerys) in succession for a King (Aerys II).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63865/discussion-on-answer-by-aegon-who-of-these-characters-has-a-more-legitimate-clai).

Comment: In fact, a female Targaryen's claim comes waaaaaaay after any legitimate male. See [Targaryen Inheritance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81326/21267).

Comment: @Möoz They don't really come into the line at all. See the edit. I removed that bit because people objected that's book only thing not applicable to show. And you already have my +1 on that one ;) Nice one

Comment: The war of the Roses, which the war of the Five Kings is mainly based on, started when a ruler died, his first son was already dead before then, and the rule was passed to the dead son's son, rather than the first **living** son of the now deceased king. The same is true here. Rhaegar died before the Mad King, and Rhaegar's siblings can argue that Rhaegar's children cannot inherit a throne that Rhaegar never held in the first place. Of course, this is open to discussion (hence the war of the Roses), but the siblings' argument does have some merit, in my opinion.

Comment: @Flater Targaryen succession doesn't work like that. Grandson by elder son comes before younger sons legally, so they can't claim that. Of course there are uncles like Euron Greyjoy anyways.

Comment: @Aegon: The rules do not apply to those who disagree with the rules and have the power to ignore those who enforce the rules. This is proven by both Stannis and Renly, who were able to amass forces to support their claim, even though Joffrey was the rightful heir (according to the rules, when he is assumed to be Robert's son). Similarly, Robert Baratheon had no rightful claim to the throne, but he took it anyway. `so they can't claim that` Semantically, they can claim anything they want. As long as there are people who believe in the claim, they can try to press their claim, even if fabricated

Comment: @Flater Renly knew he had no claim other than _his armies_, as he acknowledged himself. He never claimed to be legal heir of Robert. Stannis on the other hand claimed to be legal heir on grounds that Robert had no trueborn children. So they aren't actually valid examples. Robert had a claim to the throne through his descent from Aegon V. So no, you can't go around claiming what you want.

Comment: @Flater A better example would be Daemon Blackfyre, who was younger than Daeron II and still rose in rebellion, solely on the claim that since their father gave him the Sword, he was meant to be the successor, not his elder brother Daeron. So yes people can use words to justify some pretext. That would depend on the person. But no one goes around saying _I stronk, I taek throne_.

Answer (score 2):

Bran told us exactly who the "legitimate heir" is...

<s>Jon Snow,</s> **Aegon VII Targaryen**

The line of succession always favors males and always favors children of the heir before siblings of the monarch.

Further reading: [Comprehensive Rules for Game of Thrones Lines of Succession](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37862/comprehensive-rules-for-game-of-thrones-lines-of-succession)

The line of succession goes like this:

1. Aerys "The Mad King" - "current" monarch, now deceased
2. Rhaeghar - by rights as the first born son of Aerys, now deceased
3. Aegon VI - by rights as the first born son Rhaeghar, now deceased
4. Aegon VII (aka Jon Snow) - by right as the second born son of Rhaegar, alive!

The female line only comes into play once all male heirs are deceased, which is the crux of Danaerys' claim once her brother Viserys died. However, Viserys' claim was only considered valid because there were no other heirs (Rhaeghar and his line).

This was why Rhaegar's annulment was so important. If Rhaegar had still be married to Elia Martell, Jon Snow would still have been a bastard (assuming all other parties lived). This is why Bran initial says Jon is not a Snow but rather a Sand. The annulment make Jon a true-born heir and transforms him from Jon Snow to Aegon VII Targaryen.

Comment: Small sticking point.  I believe Jon would also be Aegon VI since his older half brother Aegon never ascended to the throne.  (So dumb that they gave two living brothers the same name, I hope this is a retconned thing by the show and not GRRM's idea).